# The structure of this sentence, "someone I know to be dead"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

The whole sentence is

> It showed someone in the castle. Someone I know to be dead.

I think it is the same as this

> Someone who I know to be dead.

and this.

> I know someone to be dead.

Is it correct? and Is "to be dead" an idiom that expresses state of someone/something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *know someone to be* in a certain condition, you know *that they are* in that condition. Your sentence could be rewritten as

> Someone who, I know, is dead.

*Someone* refers to the 'someone' mentioned in the first sentence.

> I know someone to be dead

is a different sentence, indicating what you know.